# New to add an "open in new window" and "Reset Input" into script

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to use your site properly and I cant get the CODE or HTML blocks to work so I am putting everything in Blockquotes. I am not a codemonkey so 'im looking for help because I cant figure this out even though I have tried many variation.

I am trying to get my HTML part of a javascript to open the created URL into a new window and use the "reset" to clear the text box that the code below uses. But the "reset" is not clearing the textbox (infact nothing happens when you click the reset button, and goToPage just opens the created URL in the same window, but when I replace that with say "window.open" the script stops working all together.

```
<input type="text" id="USPS_Tracking_Number" />
<input type="submit" value="Check USPS Tracking Number" 
onclick="goToPage();" 
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

help please.

Comment: Is this code wrapped into a `form` tag?

Comment: To reset a control within a form, you need to set the default value to the elements, i.e. add `value` attribute to the input to reset. What comes to the second question, you should show the code for `goToPage` function, or rather ask a new question about failed `window.open`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `input` tags inside a form tag:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="USPS_Tracking_Number" />
  <input type="button" value="Check USPS Tracking Number" onclick="goToPage();"/>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Also change the `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. Sumbit will cause the form to call a url and the `onclick` will not be triggered.

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/crnervww/)

Comment: There's some malinformation in the answer, The click listener will definitely be called before submitting the form.